# how to access the javascript under public/javascripts fold for play?

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

To access js under asset/javascripts, we could use code like the following:

```
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascript/angular.js")"></script>
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascript/user.js")"></script>
```

But how to access the files under public/javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/user.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascripts/user.js"></script>
```

i used the above path for the files inside the public.javascript, may be you map some diffrently.

how i mapped

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET    /assets/*file             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```